# Capacitor size for battery operated device?

Tags: batteries

I am planning to make a battery operated device. I am using spring contacts for the battery. Since the device will be dropped, I am planning to put in a capacitor. I just don't know what type (ceramic or electrolytic type) and value.

Can you please let me know how to compute the value? There will be three NIHM batteries (1.2V each). Maximum load is 500mA.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the capacitor? What is meant by "device will be drop"?

Comment: Capacitor can keep the power for a short time when battery is disconnected momentarily (example: when device will be drop)

Comment: You would need to tell us about the purpose of the capacitor

Comment: @PlasmaHH,The purpose of the capacitor is to keep a supply  when battery contact (spring) is bouncing/disconnected from the battery for a short period of time. I assumed this would be in micro or milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using double spring loaded contacts, so that the batteries can float a bit without losing contact.

Otherwise, measure the disconnect time for many drops, and then calculate the capacitor based on this time.

Let's say you find out that the disconnection does not last for more than 50ms.  Let's assume 100ms to be on the safe side.  Let's also assume that your system can tolerate a voltage drop to 3.0V.

$$
Q_{max} = I_{max} * t_{max} = 500mA * 100ms = 50mC \\
C_{min} = \frac{Q_{max}}{V_{drop,max}} = \frac{50mC}{3.6V - 3.0V} = 83333\mu F
$$

### Simulation

The voltage source is the batteries, the switch simulates the drop event at \$t=0\$.  Observe in the time domain simulation how the capacitor voltage drops linearly, reaching 3.0V after 100ms.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBRoL4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Conclusion

Some of the assumptions in this calculation lead to unfeasible capacitor values.  Maybe the time the contacts break typically is much shorter.  If not, reconsider whether your device will use 500mA during a drop condition.

If you still get to such large capacitor values, consider soldering in the batteries.  Or use double spring floating contacts, as suggested above.

Comment: A variation (admittedly probably too complex a method) would be to detect the fall or the break and temporarily go into a low current self-preservation mode, like a HDD retracting its heads when 0G is sensed. Then a smaller cap would be required.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the amount of capacitance needed, whatever the reason (which I don't totally understand in your question), the method usually boils down to two extremely simple formulae:

- Figure how much current, for how long, the capacitor needs to be able to give; multiply them to get the total charge : $$q=i\times t$$
- Find out the acceptable voltage drop U ; then you know that since q=c*U the capacitance you need is $$C=q/U$$

The types available are first determined by needed capacitance, max voltage and whether they must work both ways (polarized or not), then by other characteristics (price, ESR, failure modes, temperature coefficients...)

Example : if you need to supply 500mA for 10ms (that's 0.5A*0.01s=0.005C) with maximum 500mV voltage drop, you need C=0.005C/0.5V=10mF.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation in the other answer will be a great exercise. However it will tell you that you need an impractical capacitor.

You will likely want a backup battery or perhaps a better mechanical means of securing the battery for your application.

Comment: I interpreted disconnection of the batteries when dropped to be physical removal of the batteries until the user puts them back in. If you just mean the springs bouncing you might be okay.

Comment: I mean the spring bouncing.